# Indeterminate ProgressBar does not animate when part of a Dialog (JavaFX 10)

Tags: java, javafx, java-10

When a `ProgressBar` is indeterminate it has an animation that goes back and forth. This works fine when the `ProgressBar` is part of a normal `Stage` but doesn't work when part of a `Dialog`. Instead, it seems to just sit at the start of the animation. The `ProgressBar` does, however, update properly when set to some determinate value. *Note: The issue does not appear in Java 8*.

There are no indications of any exceptions.

Here's an MCVE ([GIF of it in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4dXg.gif)):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button detButton = new Button("Launch Determinate Task");
        detButton.setOnAction(ae -> {
            ae.consume();
            createDialog(primaryStage, true)
                    .showAndWait();
        });

        Button indetButton = new Button("Launch Indeterminate Task");
        indetButton.setOnAction(ae -> {
            ae.consume();
            createDialog(primaryStage, false)
                    .showAndWait();
        });

        HBox btnBox = new HBox(detButton, indetButton);
        btnBox.setSpacing(10);
        btnBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(btnBox, createDummyProgressNode());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ProgressBar Issue");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createDummyProgressNode() {
        Label label = new Label("ProgressBar to show animation in Stage.");

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        VBox box = new VBox(label, progressBar);
        box.setMaxHeight(VBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        box.setSpacing(3);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        StackPane.setAlignment(box, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        return box;
    }

    private Dialog<?> createDialog(Stage owner, boolean determinate) {
        Task<?> task = new BackgroundTask(determinate);

        Dialog<?> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.initOwner(owner);
        dialog.setTitle("Background Task - " 
                + (determinate ? "Determinate" : "Indeterminate"));

        dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefWidth(300);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(createDialogContent(task));

        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK)
                .disableProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());

        dialog.setOnShown(de -> {
            de.consume();
            executeTask(task);
        });

        return dialog;
    }

    private Node createDialogContent(Task<?> task) {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

        VBox box = new VBox(label, progressBar);
        box.setSpacing(3);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        return box;
    }

    private void executeTask(Task<?> task) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(task, "background-thread");
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    private static class BackgroundTask extends Task<Void> {

        private final boolean determinate;

        private BackgroundTask(boolean determinate) {
            this.determinate = determinate;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            final int loops = 1_000;
            for (int i = 0; i <= loops; i++) {
                updateMessage("Running... " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1L);
                if (determinate) {
                    updateProgress(i, loops);
                }
            }
            updateMessage("Complete");
            updateProgress(loops, loops);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I tried this code on:

- JDK 1.8.0_181

  - Animates normally
- JDK 10.0.2

  - Fails to animate
- OpenJDK 11-ea+22 with OpenJFX 11-ea+18

  - Fails to animate
- OpenJDK 12-ea with OpenJFX 11-ea+18

  - Fails to animate
  - *Didn't really expect a change here since the same JavaFX version is being used*.

All my tests were on a Windows 10 Home (version 1803) computer.

I'm 90% certain this is some type of regression bug, but just in case...

1. Does anyone else have this problem? Or am I doing something wrong and it's a fluke that it works on Java 8?
2. If it is a bug does anyone know of any workarounds?

I've tried things like changing the `Modality` and `owner` of the `Dialog` to no effect. It also seems to only be the `ProgressBar` as the `Dialog` can still be moved around and the message updates (i.e. the UI is not freezing).

I haven't tried this with other animated `Node`s such as `ProgressIndicator`.

*P.S. I searched the Java bug database for this or similar issue but came up with nothing; I could have easily missed one, however*.

*Update: I have submitted my own bug report*.

Comment: Seems like Java 10 did break quite a few things in JavaFX. Maybe you can try Java 9 to see if it happens. A wild *guess* is that they did not implement modules properly for JavaFX stuff.

Comment: Same behavior as you describe it on my Mac. I would just report the bug here https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug report can be found here: [JDK-8207837](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207837).

- Affected Versions: `9`, `10`, and `openjfx-11`.
- Affected Platforms: Generic (all).
- Fixed Version: `openjfx-12`.

---

Turns out the `Dialog` wasn't the root of the problem. The issue is caused by adding the `ProgressBar` to a `Scene` after the `Scene` was already added to a `Stage`; the reason this causes a problem is because of [JDK-8216377](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216377). See [this comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207837?focusedCommentId=14235706&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14235706) for more a better explanation. And here is the attached test code demonstrating the issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IndeterminateProgressBar extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 150);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // If the progress bar is added to the root after the root is
        // added to the scene and the scene is added to the stage, it will
        // fail to be shown.
        ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar();
        progBar.setProgress(-1);
        root.getChildren().add(progBar);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you move `stage.setScene(scene)` to after `root.getChildren().add(progBar)` the `ProgressBar` will animate.

Based on this information, I believe a workaround when using a `Dialog` is impossible. A `Dialog` has an internal `Stage` that it uses for display. When a `DialogPane` is set on the `Dialog` it causes the creation of a `Scene` which is then added to this `Stage`. Unfortunately, a `Dialog` is initialized with a `DialogPane` and so no matter what the `Scene` will have been added to a `Stage` before one can add the `ProgressBar`.

To avoid the issue use JavaFX 8 or OpenJFX 12+. It's possible the fix is (or will be) backported to OpenJFX 11 but I'm not sure (please leave a comment if you know one way or the other).